# Cleartimeout won't work

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to improve [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/simple-carousel/) adding events handlers to toggle play/stop when you mouseenter/mouseleave on a slide. I've seen loads of people having the same problem with the js function setTimeout and clearTimeout, and I'm having a trouble too. This is what I have

```
var autoplay;
container.mouseenter(function(){
    autoplay = setTimeout(function() {
        slide('next');
    }, config.auto);
    console.log('play');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(autoplay);
    console.log('stop');

});
```

The slides start to show up in mouseenter, but don't stop when I do the mouseleave. What I am doing wrong? It is a scope misunderstanding? I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: What is `slide('next')`?

Comment: method that makes the slide goes next. if necessary, you can check the full code here: http://code.google.com/p/simple-carousel/source/browse/trunk/simple.carousel.js

Comment: @bububaba. It's a method of the plugin

Comment: @bububaba That is what we call a function invocation. You can see the actual function definition over att Google Code, http://code.google.com/p/simple-carousel/source/browse/trunk/simple.carousel.js.

Comment: Sorry, missed the link to plugin site, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any reason why your code wouldn't work provided `container` has **exactly** one matched element in it ([working example](http://jsbin.com/ojuzul)). If there's any chance that it may match more than one element, then you'll have multiple elements sharing the same `autoplay` timer handle and it'll become a bit of a mess. If so, use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store the handle actually on the element the mouse event occurred on:

```
container.mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).data("autoplay", setTimeout(function() {
        slide('next');
    }, config.auto));
    console.log('play');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var autoplay = $(this).data("autoplay");
    if (autoplay) {
        clearTimeout(autoplay);
    }
    console.log('stop');
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ojuzul/2)

Separately, it's probably worth clearing `autoplay` (wherever you store it) when the timer fires, so you know you don't have a pending timer.

Comment: super answer. Works perfectly and now I got in mind what was my fault: indeed there is many elements sharing the `autoplay`, so storing it did the trick. Great!